# How to run two child processes in succession in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, child-process

I have two processes, one to generate a json file from an audio and the other one to normalize the json file, they are both in a function.

Each time i run the function and the first one runs, the second one refuses to run and when the second one runs, the first one refuses to run.

I want to be able to run the second one after the first one.

```
exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Normalize error", error);
      return;
    }
    if(stderr){
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      return
    } 
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  });
```

The code above is the one that generates the audio file

```
 exec(`python3 py/scale-json.py json/${song.filename}/.json`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log("I AM EXECUTING", song.filename)
        if (error) {
        console.log("Python error", error);
        }
        console.log(`stdout-python: ${stderr}`);
    })
```

While the code above normalizes it.

How do i run them one after the other ?

Comment: Why are you calling `resolve()` and `reject()`?  Is there a containing promise executor function somewhere that defines those?  If so, please show that code too.  Or did you just call those out of the blue?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  And, where's the code that tries to run these one after another?

Comment: there was a containing promise, however, i have updated it

Answer (score 2):

I'd promisify the `exec()` function and then use promise-based logic to sequence them:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function run() {
    const { stdout: stdout1, stderr: stderr1 } = await exec(command);

    // some logic based on stdout1 or stderr1
    
    const { stdout: stdout2, stderr: stderr2 } = await exec(`python3 py/scale-json.py json/${song.filename}/.json`);

    // process final results here
    return something;
}

// Call it like this:
run().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You can read about how `util.promisify()` works with `child_process.exec()` [here in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

Answer (score 0):

have u tried to use the Normalizer as a callback part?

```
 exec(`python3 py/scale-json.py json/${song.filename}/.json`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log("I AM EXECUTING", song.filename)
        if (error) {
            throw new Error (error);
        }
        console.log(`stdout-python: ${stderr}`);

        // It goes here!
        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Normalize error", error);
                return;
            }
            if(stderr){
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                reject("error");
                return;
            } 
            resolve("complete")
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        });
    })
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Ok! And let me know if it helped!